# getting error in react js while rendering component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror

I am getting below error while rendering the component from an object.

```
ype 'FC<Boxprops> | ExoticComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'FC<Boxprops>'.
  Type 'ExoticComponent<{ children?: ReactNode; }>' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent<Boxprops>'.
```

I am trying to render component on the basis of object key

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BOX, Boxprops } from './box'
import React from "react";
let obj = {
  component:'box'
}
export default function App() {

  const getComponnets = () => {
    let Component: React.FC<Boxprops> = obj.component === 'box' ? BOX : React.Fragment

    return <Component title="asd" />
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {getComponnets()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-fermat-szgggm?file=/src/App.tsx

[image: ett]

any idea.. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's right there in the screenshot what type is expected. Do try what intellisense has inferred.

[image]

```
import "./styles.css";
import { BOX, Boxprops } from "./box";
import React from "react";

let obj = {
  component: "box"
};

type IComponent =
  | React.FC<Boxprops>
  | React.ExoticComponent<{
      children?: React.ReactNode;
    }>;

export default function App() {
  const Component: IComponent = React.useMemo(
    () => (obj.component === "box" ? BOX : React.Fragment),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Component title="asd" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit getting-error-in-react-js-while-rendering-component]

Answer (score 0):

I think Box component and React.Fragment component are different component types. You have to match Fragment component to BoxProps as like Box component does.

***Try this code***

```
let Component: React.FC<Boxprops> = obj.component === 'box' ? BOX : () => <React.Fragment />;
```